# Java skips else condition

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm not sure why, but for some reason, the following code skips the `else` condition. I've tried just about everything I can think of, including switching the code blocks, but it still skips the `else` part. Basically, I want this method to return `String temp = "no"` if `String docID` that is passed to the method is not found in the `FILESTATUS` database, and `String temp = "yes"` if it is found.

```
static String checkDocID(String docID)
{
    String temp = null;

    System.out.println("Checking if data already exists in database...");
    try
    {
        Main.stmt = Main.con.createStatement();
        String command = "SELECT * FROM FILESTATUS WHERE ID='" + docID + "'";
        ResultSet queryResult = Main.stmt.executeQuery(command);
        if (!queryResult.next())
        {
            temp = "no";
        }
        else
        {
            while (queryResult.next())
            {
                String result = queryResult.getString("ID");
                if (result.equals(docID))
                {
                    temp = "yes";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Main.stmt.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    return temp;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Usually resource that require an explicit call to a close() method are closed inside a finally block. Just a little friendly advice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because you end up calling queryResult.next() in the "if" and again in the while, you're skipping the first result.  If there is only one result, the while loop will never execute.

If I can make a couple of suggestions:

- Use bound variables in a PreparedStatement rather than putting "docID" in the query string
- Don't test `result.equals(docID)` since the query already assured that.
- prefer boolean to String "yes" or "no"
- set the result to "no" or false, then set it to "yes" or true in the loop.  The extra assignment is probably faster than the extra test, plus you can skip the do{}while which most people find harder to read.

Comment: it's probably worth pointing out that `ResultSet.next` is not like `Iterator.hasNext`

Comment: Wow - I figured it was just a case of my logical brain taking a vacation. Solved it using a `do{}-while{}` as opposed to just a `while{}`, as suggested by splix.

Thank you!

Comment: I am surprised that this isn't accepted. It covers all of the unnecessary clutter in the code logic (expect of closing in finally). Maybe because you omitted the code sample?

Answer (score 6):

Might be better to restructure this loop as:

```
static String checkDocId(String docId) {
    String temp = "no";

    while (queryResult.next()) {                
        String result = queryResult.getString("ID");

        if (result.equals(docID)) {
            temp = "yes";
            break;
        }
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Some people don't like using `break` (I usually don't) so you can use a boolean in your while (I find that it reads more like english and you can tell the terminating condition right from the `while` instead of looking for an `if` inside):

```
static String checkDocId(String docId) {
    boolean found = false;

    while (queryResult.next() && !found) {
        String result = queryResult.getString("ID");
        found = result.equals(docID);
    }

    return found ? "yes" : "no";
}
```

You're performing a needless comparison otherwise. Remember, a `while` is just an `if` with a `goto` at the end ;)

As far as your problem is concerned, what Paul said is correct. Eitherway, I would still restructure the loop so that it's more elegant.

Comment: why not just `return "yes"` as soon as result is found.

Comment: That would mean you need another `return` outside the loop. I'm not a fan of multiple `return`s unless absolutely necessary. 9 times out of 10, you can rewrite your algorithm to be more elegant and remove the use of multiple `return`s.

Answer (score 3):

After a bit astonishment about the code (leaking DB resources, not trusting the DB that it returns the right `docID`, doing a `SELECT *` while you don't need all of the columns at all, not taking benefit of SQL-injection-sanitization powers of `PreparedStatement`, using `String` instead of `boolean` to denote a true/false value, a messy code flow), here's how it should *really* be done instead:

```
private static final String SQL_EXIST_DOCID = 
    "SELECT id FROM filestatus WHERE id = ?";

public boolean exist(String docID) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    boolean exist = false;

    try {
        connection = database.getConnection();
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_EXIST_DOCID);
        statement.setString(1, docID); // Shouldn't it be a Long instead? Characterbased PK's are *far* from efficient.
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        exist = resultSet.next();
    } finally {
        if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
    }

    return exist;
}
```

Clear, concise and simple as that. For more insights about using *basic JDBC* the right way you may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) useful. I hope that you take it serious to learn from it. Really.

Comment: I personally like your answer the best but to be pedantic there is no good reason to put the connection creation inside the try/catch and at least two reasons not to.  1) it makes the finally block needless complicated for connection, 2) if the try {} block gets large and some joker manages to set connection = null then you'll never close it... versus getting an NPE.

Comment: 1) can be refactored away, 2) is a programmer error. Certainly the connection should be closed in the finally, else you're leaking resources.

Comment: Although I cannot use your code exactly (as the connection is already established at this point, and needs to remain open past this point), you did open my eyes to several problems with my code... A software engineer I am not!

Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. You can in theory also replace `getConnection()` by `getTransaction()`.

Comment: @BalusC, yes the connection should be closed in the finally but it should not be created in the try... if you get an exception from create there will _never_ be a connection to close.  Why create extra complexity/problems?

Comment: @PSpeed: the connection still needs to be closed if its creation succeeds but the creation of statement or resultSet not.

Comment: @BalusC, move connection = database.getConnection() above the try {... then don't bother checking for connection != null in the finally... just close it.

Comment: @PSpeed: that's true when you leave out the `catch` on `SQLException` from the `try` block. But sometimes you'd like to add the `catch` so that you can do some logging and/or wrap it more abstractly in a custom `DAOException` or something like that.

Comment: Yeah, I can only comment on the methods that exist... not the hypothetical ones that architected differently. :)  Given the code, if I wanted to catch and wrap the exception I'd probably still push this code into a method that throws SQLException and just wrap the method.  It tends to be cleaner, and since we're talking about hypothetical future changes, you never know what other exceptions you might want to catch and log and keeping the SQL code together is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

rs.next() rolling current cursor after each call

try with

```
static String checkDocID(String docID)
{
    String temp = null;

    System.out.println("Checking if data already exists in database...");
    try
    {
        Main.stmt = Main.con.createStatement();
        String command = "SELECT * FROM FILESTATUS WHERE ID='" + docID + "'";
        ResultSet queryResult = Main.stmt.executeQuery(command);
        boolean found = queryResult.next();
        if (!found)
        {
            temp = "no";
        }
        else
        {
            do {
                String result = queryResult.getString("ID");
                if (result.equals(docID))
                {
                    temp = "yes";
                    break;
                }
            } while (queryResult.next())
        }
        Main.stmt.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly - just changing it to do {} while {} was all it needed.

Thanks!

Comment: It may work, but this code would be what others might call a minor WTF. Paul gave the real answer to the problem and vivin has a much better code implementation.

Comment: Agree with Tim regarding the WTF'ness of the accepted solution.

Comment: Although vivin's would work too, I only had to change two lines to get this (and I'm lazy!). Are there any major problems with this code? (If it makes any difference, stability is more important than speed/efficiency with this code.) Thanks!

Comment: If you want your code to be stable and maintainable then I would not go with the current solution. Using the current structure is what led you to this problem in the first place. Using the `while` without the `if` is far more maintainable. Laziness is not an excuse. You cannot be lazy and write stable/maintainable code!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling queryResult.next twice before you are trying to read it.  To prove this, put a println or something right after the else (before the while).

Since you are selecting by a particular ID, moving to next() twice will in fact fail the second time (presumably) and never execute the while block.